# How can I get the ID of the button clicked by user?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a basic multiple choice quiz using vanilla JavaScript.
How would I identify the `id` of the button the user has clicked and set this to a variable `userChoice`?

```html
<button class="answer-btn btn" id="a">Answer A</button>
<button class="answer-btn btn" id="b">Answer B</button>
<button class="answer-btn btn" id="c">Answer C</button>
<button class="answer-btn btn" id="d">Answer D</button>
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If possible you should provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) What have you tried so far? There is no JavaScript code in your question. Please edit it, and add as much as possible details. (inclduing your tried/failed js code)

Comment: ```function checkAnswer() {

  let answerBtn = document.getElementsByClassName(answer-btn);
  let userChoice = answerBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert(target.id)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use event delegation on the nearest static ancestor. `event.target.id` will give the id of the clicked element.

```js
document.getElementById("wrapper").addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let userChoice = e.target.id;
  console.log(userChoice);
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<button class="answer-btn btn" id="a">Answer A</button>
<button class="answer-btn btn" id="b">Answer B</button>
<button class="answer-btn btn" id="c">Answer C</button>
<button class="answer-btn btn" id="d">Answer D</button>
</div>
```

Comment: There's only one rule of thumbs for using `target`, and that's in pair with `.closest()`. Always, from muscle-memory, use `currentTarget`. Only when you really know what you're doing -  than use `target`.

Answer (score -1):

- Use: [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- Use [NodeList.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)
- Use [Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) (or `this` if you don't use an Arrow function)

```js
const getAnswer = (ev) => {
  const userChoice = ev.currentTarget.id;
  console.log(userChoice);
};

const ELS_btn = document.querySelectorAll(".answer-btn");
ELS_btn.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", getAnswer));
```

```html
<button type="button" class="answer-btn btn" id="a">Answer A</button>
<button type="button" class="answer-btn btn" id="b">Answer B</button>
<button type="button" class="answer-btn btn" id="c">Answer C</button>
<button type="button" class="answer-btn btn" id="d">Answer D</button>
```